# getDownloadUrl() method is deprecated after firebase update

Tags: android, firebase

`getDownloadUrl()` method is deprecated after firebase update. What is the alternative code for this method?

```
public void createOrUpdatePostWithImage(Uri imageUri, final OnPostCreatedListener onPostCreatedListener, final Post post) {

    // Register observers to listen for when the download is done or if it fails
    DatabaseHelper databaseHelper = ApplicationHelper.getDatabaseHelper();
    if (post.getId() == null) {
        post.setId(generatePostId());
    }

    final String imageTitle = ImageUtil.generateImageTitle(UploadImagePrefix.POST, post.getId());
    UploadTask uploadTask = databaseHelper.uploadImage(imageUri, imageTitle);

    if (uploadTask != null) {
        uploadTask.addOnFailureListener(exception -> {
            // Handle unsuccessful uploads
            onPostCreatedListener.onPostSaved(false);

        }).addOnSuccessListener(taskSnapshot -> {
            // taskSnapshot.getMetadata() contains file metadata such as size, content-type, and download URL.
            Uri downloadUrl = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();
            LogUtil.logDebug(TAG, "successful upload image, image url: " + String.valueOf(downloadUrl));

            post.setImagePath(String.valueOf(downloadUrl));
            post.setImageTitle(imageTitle);
            createOrUpdatePost(post);

            onPostCreatedListener.onPostSaved(true);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: You should first check the documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/upload-files, what you want to do is documented in the section right after uploading.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code I to get the ImagesUrl.

I hope it works!

I also got a repository on github for this, here is the link.
https://github.com/BVLD/Firebase-Storage-upload-and-retreive-images-android-studio

```
 ImagesPath.putFile(mainImageURI).continueWithTask(new Continuation<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot, Task<Uri>>() {
            @Override
            public Task<Uri> then(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) throws Exception {
                if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                    throw task.getException();
                }
                return ImagesPath.getDownloadUrl();
            }
        }).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Uri>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Uri> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {


                    Uri downUri = task.getResult();
                    downUri.toString();
```